# highcharts export timestamp not converting to date

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts export csv works but the x-axis timestamp is not converting to the dateFormat.
xls export dateFormat also not working.

I can change the exporting.csv.delimiter and it changes the delimiter.
But the exporting.csv.dateFormat is not used and csv contains the timestamp.

export-data is * @license Highcharts JS v6.2.0 (2018-10-17)

Using

I've stepped thru into the highcharts.export-data.getCsv().getDataRows() method and the pick() code that refs the dateFormat is not hit. The dateformat value is loaded but not used.

I've tried converting the timestamp in the series to a formatted datetime prior to calling export-data and it results in undefined in the csv file.

Thanks

Comment: Some progress, fixed the formatting when manually replacing the timestamp in the series before the export..
Now instead of undefined I get just 0..n ( I guess the row index?) in the datetime field.

0,324.42689,1.4211538039,394.6318860661,175.9299161175
1,186.8694458,1.3966503917,391.9529132996,175.9434575631
2,184.9517522667,1.3880855295,391.9612086949,175.4341303537
3,191.2374245333,1.3581240302,392.1527047294,175.3893355041

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on?